# Why does Pandas add numbers at beginning of csv-file after converting

Tags: python, pandas

I am a Python beginner and am currently trying to delete some columns in a csv - worked well! But: When I use pandas, it adds another column automatically at the beginning of the file and adds row numbers. How can I avoid that?

Input data is as follow (json):

```
    [
      {
        "source": "twitter",
        "cashtag": "$FB",
        "sentiment score": "0.366",
        "id": "719659409228451840",
        "spans": [
          "watching for bounce tomorrow"
    ]
  }, ... ]
```

Converting to csv worked well.
My code for doing this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Convert son to csv
pd.read_json("test.json").to_csv("test.csv")

# Delete cashtag, id, source column
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
data = data.drop(["cashtag", "id", "source"], axis=1)
data.to_csv("test_cleaned.csv")
data.head()
```

Output:

```
Unnamed: 0  sentiment score spans
0   0   0.366   ['watching for bounce tomorrow']
1   1   0.638   ['record number of passengers served in 2015']
2   2   -0.494  ['out $NFLX -.35']
3   3   0.460   ['Looking for a strong bounce', 'Lunchtime 
4   4   0.403   ['Very intrigued with the technology and
```

What I want to have:

```
sentiment score spans
    0.366   ['watching for bounce tomorrow']
    0.638   ['record number of passengers served in 2015']
    -0.494  ['out $NFLX -.35']
    0.460   ['Looking for a strong bounce', 'Lunchtime 
    0.403   ['Very intrigued with the technology and
```

So converting and deletion worked well, but for each operation using pandas, it adds another column at the beginning of the file. In this example 1 column after converting to csv and 1 column after deleting columns. How can I avoid this?

Comment: The pandas online documentation is a great resource. When trying to figure out how a function works, this is a great place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column you're referring to is the index. Try doing this when saving your csv:

```
data.to_csv("test_cleaned.csv", index=False)
```

Pandas automatically creates an index for each Dataframe you initialize, unless you do it explicitly. I highly recommend giving a read to [panda's documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) to get more info.

Answer (score 2):

That’s called an index, you can prevent it being written by using the following

```
df.to_csv(‘FileMaker.csv’, index=False)
```